# Issue dynamically populating select list with server-side Blazor

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side, asp.net-core-3.0, matblazor

Trying to populate a select drop down list dynamically & every time I run it, I can step through the code just fine all the way through the @foreach block, but then it seems to get stuck in a continuous loop or something & will completely freeze up everything! Struggling because no error is even occurring.

"/api/Reps/Index" Controller works separately just fine.  And I even updated it to just return one rep to see if that was an issue, but didn't make any difference.

*Note: Using MatBlazor to implement Material Design.

My .Razor Page:

```
@inject HttpClient Http

<EditForm Model="@projectParameters">
  <DataAnnotationsValidator />
  <ValidationSummary />

  <div>
    <MatSelect Label="Rep" @bind-Value="@projectParameters.Rep">
        <MatOption Value="">Select</MatOption>
        @foreach (var rep in repList)
          {
           <MatOption Value="@rep.id.ToString()">@rep.name</MatOption>
          }
    </MatSelect>
  </div>
</EditForm>

@code
{
  Project projectParameters = new Project();
  private MyRep[] repList { get; set; }

  protected override async Task OnInitAsync()
  {
    repList = await Http.GetJsonAsync<MyRep[]>
    ("/api/Reps/Index");
  }
}
```

Here is my RepsController.cs code, too:

```
namespace MyProject.Controllers
{
    public class RepsController : Controller
    {
        MyDataAccessLayer objrep = new MyDataAccessLayer();

        [HttpGet]
        [Route("api/Reps/Index")]
        public IEnumerable<MyRep> Index()
        {
            return objrep.GetAllReps();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not so sure that no error is occurring, as the first render will throw because MyRep is null. Try initialising MyRep or wrapping the foreach with an if to guard against null?

Comment: Hell, you're right.  That's all it was!  Added an if to check for null first & voila.  Any idea why it was causing such drastic effects on my program (and computer) instead of just error'ing out first pass through?

Comment: No, but I'll blame something async something

Comment: @MisterMagoo: What about to initializate repList: `private MyRep[] repList { get; set; } = new MyRep[0];`. The error is raised when OP try to iterate over a null.

Comment: @herrera , well spotted, that's what I meant to say of course

Answer (score 0):

Just add @key attribute that equals to your option value, so code example:

```
<select>
     <option @key="@rep.id" value="@rep.id">@rep.name</option>
</select>
```